# How do I remove html tags and other characters from a text field

Tags: php, html, sql, joomla

The fields contains the value of : {"93":" Size:</span>XL</span>"}. I want to display only Size: XL. I have tried using the strip_tag function but have been unsuccessful. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: What did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: If it is really "</span>XL</span>", then something is seriously wrong. It isn't even a tag, so strip_tags will fail, of course.

Comment: the source of the fields is? looks like JSOM to me

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Its json encoded value.

```
 $text = '{"93":" Size:</span>XL</span>"}';
 $ar = json_decode($text);  

 foreach($ar as $value){
    echo strip_tags($value);
   }
```

The output will be

```
Size:XL
```

Hope its fixed ..

Comment: I am pulling the field from a database with a select statement. The field is text. I have tried the replace function and the strip_tags function. How would i go about changing the value after pulling it?

Comment: just decode that value with json like above and you can access with foreach()

Comment: What part in this exactly it's removing the tags? To my understanding they are still there, you just don't see it because its HTML and the browser won't display the tags.

Comment: @Havenard You are right any of the above code portion didn't remove html tags but check his json_encoded string its not <span> its </span> so after the json_decode() that is not a valid tag its remove, check browser source code too. For the clear answer i will update the answer too thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If your tag was correct, like so:

`<span>XL</span>` instead of `</span>XL</span>`,

`strip_tags()` should work for you.

I verified with the following test...

```
$text = "<span>XL</span>";
$goodtext = strip_tags($text);
```

And output the results...

```
echo htmlentities($text)
echo "<br/>";
echo htmlentities($goodtext);
```

Yielded...

```
<span>XL</span>
XL
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was a bit unclear, if the field contains all there including the { brackets, then this regex in a replace should help, just replace the characters with an empty string:

```
/"\:"|[^A-Za-z:]|span/g
```

If that is not the case and you only have the second string with the spans, you could use this one:

```
/[^A-Za-z:]|span/g
```

Be warned though, it also removes spaces and only works in specific cases, eg. does not remove other tags etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a global regular expression match using the function `preg_match_all` to extract only "Size: XX" from your field.

```
$field = "your data fields"
$pattern = "/(Size:)<\/span>([a-z]{1,2})<\/span>/i";

preg_match_all($pattern,$field,$result,PREG_SET_ORDER);                                  
foreach( $result as $r ) {
    print($r[1]." ".$r[2].PHP_EOL);
}
```

Will output:

```
Size: XL
Size: L
...
```